# Any way to mount a TrueCrypt Windows system partition remotely through LogMeIn after a WOL?

Tags: remote, truecrypt, wake-on-lan, logmein

I have a Windows computer that I've encrypted the OS of. I would like to be able to connect to this computer after a Wake On LAN through some means (I have DynDNS configured so it doesn't have to be through LogMeIn) and mount the encrypted Windows. Is there any way to do that?

My initial thoughts were to create a separate unencrypted Linux partition and connect into that, then mount the Windows drive through that but I'm not sure there's actually a way to pull that off.

Thoughts? I know I can just encrypt most of my folders on Windows without encrypting the whole system but I'd prefer to have the whole thing encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your computer has a newer version of Intel AMT, you could configure that to give you KVM access over IP.

Any solution to the problem is going to require some type of remote console access, whether it be AMT, IPMI or a hardware KVM that supports management over IP. LogMeIn doesn't have that level of access.

Answer (score 1):

Since LogMeIn doesn't give you access to the TrueCrypt bootloader, you'll need to either decrypt the system partition or mount it from an unencrypted system as you suggested.  That will only give you file access though, you won't be able to boot into Windows.

One other alternative (that probably isn't very helpful) would be to run the encrypted OS in a virtual machine (like VMware Player/Workstation).  You can use LogMeIn to connect to the unencrypted host OS, then run the VM to access the encrypted system.  Seems like a lot of hassle though.